# Heatmap with 10000 * 400 points in java

Tags: java, image, heatmap

I want to show users a heatmap with 10000 * 400 tiles. Current state in my program is that I have a class which is a `JComponent`. In this `JComponent`, I have instances of `Image` for the tiles. If I had a 300 * 300 matrix, the program uses between 800 and 1000 MB ram. This is too much.

What can I do else or has someone a control which can show such a big heatmap?

Today I have tested [`JHeatChart`](http://code.google.com/p/jheatchart/), which creates a `BufferedImage`. There the size for a 10000 * 400 matrix is under 400 MB, but the class needs over 15 Minutes to create it. This is too long.

Has anybody some idee or knows an control which can handle the data?

Comment: Do you load the image each time you create a new tile? The memory usage seems really high. you may want to post relevant code around your tile creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this will be a map, you do not need to create a component for each tile. many of them can be re-used. What you want to do is during initialization of the app, create a map of all possible components, and then on each tile pass a reference to that component.

Here would be an example.

```
public class HeatMap{

private static List<JComponent> tiles = new ArrayList<JComponent>();    
private List<JComponent> heatmap = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
private Random rand = new Random();

static{
    tiles.add(new JLabel("Cold"));
    tiles.add(new JLabel("Hot"));
    tiles.add(new JLabel("Warm"));
}

public HeatMap(){
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<400; j++){
                heatmap.add(tiles.get(rand.nextInt(3)));            
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the above case we only have to create 3 tiles, the rest  are references to those. This type of approach should help reduce your memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

You could try scaling your map. So instead of priniting every single tile to your screen, if your zoomed far away, use bigger tiles. One could also try to merging the single tiles to one object instead of keeping references for every single tile.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, 10000 * 400 tiles is too many to view at once. Instead, use the [fly-weight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to render only the tiles that are visible in the viewport of a `JScrollPane`. [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Does a tile really have to be represented as an image or would a colored box be sufficient?

If a colored box would be sufficient you might just draw the visible tiles in your `paint(...)` method. There would be no need to load those images.

If it has to be images, I assume that not every tile is unique, thus instead of loading an image per tile you might try and load all needed images once and have the tiles reference the corresponding image. Thus if you have 100 different images, instead of having 4000000 copies you'd have 100 and 4000000 quite small references.

Answer (score 1):

Any way you present it, the user will never be able to perceive four million data points simultaneously. Therefore you should never have four million graphical widgets. Either the display should be scaled down, or (when zoomed in) you should display only a subset of all tiles at a time. Either way you will have to map the notional 4,000,000 to far fewer graphical widgets and reuse those you already have.

As other answers have specified, you should also look into using the simplest possible widget type that will do the job.